# How do I check if a string contains a substring in appway script?

Tags: appway

The `CONTAINS($val1, $val2, $delim)` function in AppwayScript checks whether a delimiter separated string contains a certain value as a substring.

So, e.g.:

```
CONTAINS('a|b|c', 'b', '|') == true
```

but

```
CONTAINS('aa|bb|cc', 'b', '|') == false
```

How do I perform a simple string inclusion test in AppwayScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead, try:

```
MATCH('aa|bb|cc', 'b')
```